# Что такое композитный primary key?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Сегодня случайно наткнулся на словосочетание "композитный primary key". Сразу начал гуглить и ничего конкретного найти не смог - везде это словосочетание используется в контексте и без объяснения чем это является.

Не могли бы вы, пожалуйста, понятным языком объяснить что это и для чего нужно (небольшой пример).

До сегодняшнего дня для меня существовал самый простой в этом понимании primary key. Ну еще и foreign key - тоже в простом понимании (`author_id` для таблицы `posts`, например).

Comment: В русскоязычной литературе чаще встречается под названием "составной ключ". По этому запросу первая же ссылка: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Композитный первичный ключ - это ключ определяемый сочетанием нескольких колонок. Например таблица каких-то людей

```
CREATE TABLE persons (
   first_name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
   last_name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
   age SMALLINT,
   gender BOOLEAN,
   PRIMARY KEY(first_name, last_name)
);
```

Назначение первичного ключа - уникально идентифицировать запись. Если мы на все 100% уверены, что полные тёзки в нашей таблице зарегистрированы не будут, то можем сделать ключ по имени и фамилии.

Comment: А можно небольшой пример, пожалуйста? А то я правда не до конца понимаю для чего это нужно...

Comment: После того как вы добавили пример кода, я немного понял что это. Но как это работает на практике и для чего вообще нужно - вопрос остался открытым. Но интересно понять...

Comment: Композитный ключ нужен для того же, для чего и обычный.

Comment: Другими словами - зачем два поля `first_name` и `last_name` вместо привычного `id` (в рамках вашего примера)? Я понимаю что если нужно использовать `id`, то и вопросов нет. Но при каких обстоятельствах может понадобиться связка из вашего примера или даже связка из двух `..._id`?

Comment: Вы дополнили свой ответ. Не заметил сразу. Все понял. Спасибо вам.